# How to assign a variable in to an object of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array like this,

```
var items = ['1','2','3']
```

and i want the output as 
    newItems = [{'id':1}.{'id':2},{'id':3}];

```
  newItems = [{'id':''}]
  for(var i = 0;i<items.length;i++){
           newItems[i].id = type[i];
  }
```

Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map` method for this, which creates a new array and applies a `provided` **callback** function for every item in the array.

```js
var items = ['1','2','3']
console.log(items.map(function(item){
  return {"id":item}
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `map`:

`newItems = items.map(function(item) { return {'id': parseInt(item) }; });`

EDIT: I added `parseInt()` since the user's desired output included unquoted integers.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var items = ['1','2','3'];
var newItems = items.map(function(item) {
  var obj = {};
  obj.id = +item; // '+' if you wish to convert item from string to number
  return obj;
});

console.log(newItems); //[{'id':1},{'id':2},{'id':3}]
```